# Cannot import com.google.android.gms.analytics after upgrading to Google Play Services 7+

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services

My application currently uses Google Play Services version 6.5.87. When I tried to upgrade to the latest version (7+), I get compiler errors trying to import com.google.android.gms.analytics. I cannot find any evidence that this library has been deprecated or does not work with the latest google play. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Try Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files, to make sure that Android Studio picked up your dependency change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From version 6.5, you can selectively compile Google Play service APIs into your app.

In version 6.5 analytics is included in `play-services-base`. From Google Play Services 7.0 analytics has his own description `play-services-analytics` and it is no more included in the base description.

Add this line to your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.3.0'
}
```